# Getting total of sum using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query returns the following Output.

**Output**

```
BrandName   Amount
brand1      314.00
brand1      24.00
brand2      75.00
brand2      48.00
```

The desired Output is getting the total amount for each brand like below

```
BrandName   Amount
brand1      338.00
brand2      123.00
```

**Query**

```
SELECT Brands.BrandName,
  SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge - ((SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge) * Orders.Discount / 100) AS Amount

FROM dbo.Orders

INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
  ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID


INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails
  ON dbo.OrderDetails.OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands
  ON dbo.Brands.BrandID = dbo.Outlets.BrandID

GROUP BY 
Orders.OrderID,
dbo.Orders.DeliveryCharge,
Orders.Discount,
Brands.BrandName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Common Table Expression` for your scenairo

```
With MyGroupCte as 
(
SELECT Brands.BrandName,
  SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge - ((SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge) * Orders.Discount / 100) AS Amount

FROM dbo.Orders

INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
  ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID


INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails
  ON dbo.OrderDetails.OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands
  ON dbo.Brands.BrandID = dbo.Outlets.BrandID

GROUP BY 
Orders.OrderID,
dbo.Orders.DeliveryCharge,
Orders.Discount,
Brands.BrandName
)
SELECT BrandName, SUM(Amount) FROM MyGroupCte 
GROUP BY BrandName;
```

Answer (score 0):

do it Like this:

```
SELECT grp.BrandName,sum(Amount)as Total_Amount from
(SELECT Brands.BrandName,
  SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge - ((SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge) * Orders.Discount / 100) AS Amount

FROM dbo.Orders

INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
  ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID


INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails
  ON dbo.OrderDetails.OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands
  ON dbo.Brands.BrandID = dbo.Outlets.BrandID

GROUP BY 
Orders.OrderID,
dbo.Orders.DeliveryCharge,
Orders.Discount,
Brands.BrandName) as grp
group by BrandName
```